# Не могу получить XPath Кнопки "Like" в Инстаграм

Tags: python, selenium, instagram

Использую Selenium, открываю станицу с хештегом в инстаграм, открываю первый пост и пытаюсь поставить лайк

Код:

```
driver.get(f'https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/{hashtag}/')
time.sleep(2)

hrefs = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'a')

posts_urls = [item.get_attribute('href') for item in hrefs if "/p/" in item.get_attribute('href')]

for url in posts_urls[0:1]:
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(2)
    like_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='_aamw']")
    like_button_span = like_button.find_element(By.XPATH, "div/div/span")
    button_status = like_button_span.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'svg').get_attribute('aria-label')
    if button_status == 'Нравится':
        like_button.click()

    time.sleep(5)

driver.quit()
```

В итоге ошибка что нет такого элемента на странице:

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[@class='_aamw']"}
  (Session info: chrome=116.0.5845.96); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
Stacktrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF685AC52A2+57122]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF685A3EA92]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF68590E3AB]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF685947D3E]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF685947E2C]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF685980B67]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF68596701F]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF68597EB82]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF685966DB3]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF68593D2B1]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF68593E494]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF685D6EF82+2849794]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF685DC1D24+3189156]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF685DBACAF+3160367]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF685B56D06+653702]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF685A4A208]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF685A462C4]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF685A463F6]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF685A367A3]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFB1BA27614+20]
    RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFB1D8E26B1+33]


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

like_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='xp7jhwk']")

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]